# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage

Tags: java, pdfbox

Getting this error when extracting text from PDF files from a Java service. Use JDK 1.8 and PDFbox 1.8.6 on Windows Server.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and use the latest 1.8.* version (or 2.0.* if possible). Make sure that pdfbox an fontbox have the same version and clean up other versions from the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Stack Trace]

Added stack trace. Issue was the awt.dll was not in the PATH. Added the C:\jdku275b-01\jre\bin to the system PATH and restarted the server. It is working now.